# Redirect 301 - remove .html extension from URLs

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to remove the `.html` extension from my urls, located into specific directory and redirect 301 them.

Here is how the structure looks like:

```
mysite.com/category/nameofcategory/pagenumber.html
```

The thing is that `nameofcategory` and `pagenumber` could be any letter or number.

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend having your content scattered in many html-files in different folders. This becomes very impractical if you for example want to change the layout of your pages.

Storing the content in a database is a much better solution. If that's not possible perhaps the html files could contain only the formatted text content and a back end script could embed that content to a layout when the page is requested.

This requires that the mod_rewrite module is enabled in the Apache configuration.

In both cases all of the requests would be routed through the back end script and the .htaccess might look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

This part of the regex: `([^/.]+)` matches and captures a string that doesn't contain the characters / or . and is 1 characters long or longer. The captured strings can be referenced with $1, $2 and so on.

Now the pretty urls like mysite.com/category/foo/bar work. In addition we need to define a rule that redirects the old urls ending in ".html". The rule required might look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+).html$ category/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

One thing to remember while testing and adjusting the redirects is that the redirect may get cached in the browser which may lead to confusing results when testing.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `.html` extension on the URL and 301 redirect to the extensionless URL you can try the following in the .htaccess in your "specific directory":

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /specific-directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
```